# WCF Service - The resource cannot be found

Tags: wcf

I am deployed my published the WCF web service to my server and when i am tryihg to
access it its giving me following error????

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /API/Errors/GeneralError.aspx

Comment: /API/Errors/GeneralError.aspx doesn't really look and feel like a WCF service address....

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information? What does your service look like? What bindings are you using (SOAP vs. REST)? What are you trying to do?? Are you hosting in IIS (IIS6 or IIS7?), or self-hosting??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an application pool issue, on recycling the application pool the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it has to do with the handlers setup in IIS...

read this http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/jpsmit/archive/2007/01/17/wcf-http-404-when-hosted-in-iis.aspx